# Redux action creator slightly the same accross diffrent pages

Tags: react-redux

I am currently working with redux, I just encounter a function that is almost the same for the other pages the only difference is the services that is using in method.how can i make it DRY in redux.

please take note that I am using combineReducer and router for different pages.

e.g:
in - InsuranceCompanyIndex.js

```
export function fetchInsuranceCompanies() {
return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const state = getState();
        dispatch({ type: LOADING });
        InsuranceCompany.paginate(state.dataTable.tableFilter).then(
            (response) => dispatch(setInsuranceCompanies(response.data))
        );
    };
}
```

in - InsuranceCompanyLines.js

```
export function fetchInsuranceLines() {
     return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const state = getState();
        dispatch({ type: LOADING });
        InsuranceLines.paginate(state.dataTable.tableFilter).then(
            (response) => dispatch(setInsuranceLines(response.data))
        );
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use closure like this

```
export function fetchInsuranceData(InsuranceData,setInsuranceData) {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
         const state = getState();
         dispatch({ type: LOADING});
         InsuranceData.paginate(state.dataTable.tableFilter).then(
            (response) => dispatch(setInsuranceData(response.data))
        );
    };
}
```

Now everytime you call fetchInsuranceDat, just pass these two (InsuranceData, setInsuranceData) varibles and it will return a function which will have access to these two varibles.